# Improving contenteditable typing performance

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, contenteditable

Typing is slow in content editable if the content is long(length varies according to the device) in android WebView.To improve the performance, I was looking to implement the below options. But I'm not sure whether this would have significant improvement in the typing speed.

1. Having only the current focused div visible and nearby div's visible
   and set the visibility of the other div to `display: none`.
2. Having set the content editable false to other div's except the focussed div.

I also considered replacing the content editable div with other non-content editable based editors which are available. But the problem is most of them are based on Codemirror and `Codemirror` has issues in auto-correct and focus in android `WebView`.

https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/issues/6145

Rewriting the editor from scratch will take a lot of time. So just wondering if this could improve the performance of typing in long content content-editable divs. Suggestions for improving typing speed are most welcome.

Google Docs was revamped with the editor which was not based on content-editable but not sure how it works without the `WebView` not allowing to intercept keypress events in javascript side.

Reference link:

[Google Docs Editor](https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html)